# No error messages returned when mysql_connect does not work for PHP on IIS

Tags: php, mysql, iis-6

I am new to PHP and MySQL and have recently installed both PHP v5.3.10 and MySQL v 5.5.21 on a Windows Server 2003 server already running IIS v6.

PHP runs and I have created a database on MySQL from the MySQL 5.5 Command Line Client.
However, when I try to access the database from PHP with the following commands:

```
echo "Open database";
$link = mysql_connect($host, $username, $password);
echo " link: $link";
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db($db_name, $link)or die("cannot select DB");

echo " database open";
```

I get the following returned to the web page:

```
Open database
```

No error messages are produced and nothing after the mysql_connect command is returned from 
the PHP to the screen.

Also tried line below which also did not return any error messages:

```
mysql_connect($host, $username, $password) or die('Cannot connect:' . mysql_error());
```

Anybody have any ideas why I can't make a connection and can't get an error message back from mysql_connect command?

I have checked MySQL and I have tried defining the host as %, localhost, the local host IP and the IP:port number (from the port number 3306 listed in the my.ini) to no effect.
I only have one username of 'root' created in mySQL with a single password (which I used when I opened MySQL to create the database)

The 'php.ini' I have placed in both the 'C:\Program Files\PHP' and 'C:\WINDOWS'.
This file contains 'extension_dir = "C:\Program Files\PHP\ext"' to specify the extension directory and includes the following at the end of the file:

[PHP_PDO_MYSQL]

```
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
```

[PHP_MYSQL]

```
extension=php_mysql.dll
```

[PHP_MYSQLI]

```
extension=php_mysqli.dll
```

Also I tried running phpinfo() and it returned the following table for mysqlnd:

```
mysqlnd                enabled 
Version                mysqlnd 5.0.8-dev - 20102224 - $Revision: 321634 $  
Compression            supported  
SSL                    supported  
Command buffer         size  4096  
Read buffer            size  32768  
Read timeout           31536000  
Collecting statistics  Yes  
Collecting memory statistics  No  
Tracing                       n/a
```

So Is I assume the php should be able to connect.

Comment: Are error messages turned on?

Comment: You'd get a fatal php error on undefined functions, like mysql_connect not existing. The functions would simply NOT be present AT ALL if the underlying modules weren't loaded to begin with.

Comment: From the undefined function mysql_connect() error message it looks like your right. How do I go about loading the module if the php.ini file is not loading them?

Comment: This seems to be a topic of another question.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Answer (score 0):

To mirror @Jrod:

- is error_reporting on?
- have you checked the error_log for the instance?

It sounds like something's failing and your error reporting isn't set high enough to show it. You might try addin this to the top of the script:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Comment: Inserting this line at the top of the php resulted in the web page not being displayed at all. It needed the ini_set command to display the error