# Why am I getting no errors from this?

Tags: php, error-reporting

I have this code and for some reason it just won't give me any errors when I pass in invalid data. At least I would expect to get either wrong database or the standard `'Access denied for user 'root@localhost'`. I have experienced lots of these mystical non-showing errors after I moved to PHP 5.4 and it's getting bothersome. Have I overlooked something really silly here? Any help appreciated.

```
mysql_connect('localhost', 'wrong', 'wrong') or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('wrong'); or die(mysql_error()); # <--- Somehow a semi-colon appeared inside this line and kept php/mysql from showing errors.

php.ini: display_errors = On, error_reporting = E_ALL
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://j.mp/Rj2iVR) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: is ";" intentional before "or die" ?

Comment: I'm 100% aware that they're deprecated but I wouldn't expect PHP to not let me use them at all. I'm using them on purpose to refresh my skills, I use PDO in all of my projects.

Comment: First of all, use `mysqli`. :P Second of all, `mysql_select_db('wrong'); or die(mysql_error());` shouldn't have that first semi-colon... `mysql_select_db('wrong') or die(mysql_error());`

Comment: What error were you expecting? What "invalid data" were you passing in to cause an error?

Comment: That semi-colon was a mispelling. Must have got it there after moving my code to the textarea.

Comment: @Jeremy He didn't get an error, he just WANTS to get that error...

Comment: Are you sure you're setting the PHP ini stuff before the code is run?

Comment: What does `error_log` set up?

Comment: Actually it seems that semi-colon must have been in my production code too. I find this -really- weird though as I wrote it both without and with the die-clause and I got nothing at all.

Comment: @MrXenotype Please re-read my comment. His post says that he was expecting an error due to "invalid data". I was asking which error he was expecting, and/or which data he expected to cause it.

Comment: @Jeremy: Ah, sorry, must have mis-read. As for the question, have you tried just adding `ini_set('display_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` right before connection? This guy seems have the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9604145/no-error-messages-returned-when-mysql-connect-does-not-work-for-php-on-iis

Comment: @MRXenoType Ye, that's one of the first things I tried. I also reinstalled XAMPP. Found the error now, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The extra `;` in the line,

```
mysql_select_db('wrong') or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: I don't think you have to unless you want to use explicit MySQL connection resources to pass around. I never bothered as I only used global connections in my old code when I used to use the mysql_* extension.

Comment: connection object is optional

Comment: The OP seems to have edited the typo.

Comment: I must have missed this semi-colon as I got errors from both lines when I removed it. I find this weird, though, as I didn't have the die-clause there at first and I still didn't get anything. However, I had the same problem with PDO not showing exceptions even though I set it to show them. The solution was to use a new line and call the `setAttribute()` method independently. Thanks to everyone for helping me clear up this silly mistake :)!

Answer (score 0):

Blank screen is often a parse error